# Bootstrap popover not working after scrolled

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, listview, yii2, scroll-paging

I showing content in bootstrap popover row, after i scrolled to second or thrid page bootstrap popover not working,

```
<?php echo ListView::widget([
                     'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                     'itemOptions' => ['style'=>'float:left;','class' => 'item'],
                     'itemView' => '_item',
                     'pager' => [
                        'class' => \kop\y2sp\ScrollPager::className(),
                        'triggerOffset' => 100,
                        'noneLeftText' => 'You reached the end',                        
                        'noneLeftTemplate' => '<div class="ias-noneleft" style="text-align: center;clear:both;">{text}</div>',
                     ],
                     'summary' =>false,
                ]); ?>


<a  data-toggle="popover" data-placement='right' 
                          data-content='<div>Welcome to the yii2 scroll pager</div>' 
                          class="rec_popover"
                          href="<?=Url::toRoute(['list/view','rid' => $list['id']]);?>" data-lightbox-group="3D">
                          <img src="images/list-1.png"  border="0" style="width:190px;height:107px;" />
</a>
```

Please help me to fix this

Comment: Hey @sasi! Did my answer solve your problem or do you need more information?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the extension you are using (ScrollPager) but I am sure where the problem lies. Here is the deal:

### Problem

The ScrollPager loads data via XHR (AJAX) as I suppose. This means after receiving new records they get appended to your current HTML-code. The popover gets attached to all elements having the attribute `data-toggle="popover"` by default. This happens *after the initial loading of your page*.

Because your new records are loaded at a later point in time, the popover-handler does not get attached to them.

### Solution

You need to attach the popover-handler manually. This can be done in several different ways:

- Catch a javascript event of your extension (if there is one)
- or catch the global ajax-event when a request is completed

The later having the advantage that it works extension independently.

### JS-Code

The following js-code will get executed whenever an AJAX-call returns and reattach the popover to all relevant targets. This should solve your problem once and forever.

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    //selector to fetch all popover-targets
    var popoverTargets = $('[data-toggle="popover"]');
    //iterate over them
    popoverTargets.each(function (i, el) {
        //remove popover if already attached
        $(this).popover('destroy');
        //re-attach popover
        $(this).popover();
    });
});
```

Note that this uses the popover default settings. If you want to customize this, simply provide an object as parameter to the `popover()`-call.

Hope it helps!